# Problemas con Impresora en navegador

Tags: javascript, laravel, json, usb

Tengo una app web que imprime directamente al usb, probe con zadig y funciono, pero al reiniciar la maquina se desconecta y debo conectar y desconectar el aparato varias veces para que lo levante denuevo, hay alguna forma de que quede conectado siempre?, es un problema de windows 10?
Agradeceria su ayuda.

```
<script>
var device;
function setup(device) {
    return device.open()
    .then(() => device.selectConfiguration(1))
    .then(() => device.claimInterface(0))
}
function print() {
    var string = document.getElementById("printContent").innerHTML + "\n";
    var encoder = new TextEncoder();
    var data = encoder.encode(string);
    device.transferOut(1, data)
    .then(() => {
            window.location.href = '/sales/create';
        }
    })
    .catch(error => { console.log(error); })
}
function connectAndPrint() {
    if (device == null) {
        navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{ vendorId: 0x0416 }] })
        .then(selectedDevice => {
            device = selectedDevice;
            console.log(device);
            return setup(device);
        })
        .then(() => print())
        .catch(error => { console.log(error); })
    }
    else
        print();
}
navigator.usb.getDevices()
  .then(devices => {
    if (devices.length > 0) {
        device = devices[0];
        return setup(device);
     }
    })
    .catch(error => { console.log(error); });
```

Comment: Que has intentaod ? sube tu codigo

Comment: Hola Francisco, ahi agregue el codigo.